# Is it true that $(\Delta\varphi)\phi=\nabla \cdot(\nabla\phi)\varphi-\nabla\phi\cdot\nabla\varphi$ for complex-valued functions $\phi$ and $\varphi$?

Tags: vector-analysis

I know from vector calculus that for a complex-valued functions $\phi$ and $\varphi$ say, the following identity hold: $$\phi\Delta\varphi=\nabla \cdot(\varphi\nabla \phi)-\nabla \phi \cdot \nabla \varphi.$$ 
This is an obvious identity from 
$$\nabla \cdot(\varphi\nabla \phi)=\phi\Delta\varphi+\nabla \phi \cdot \nabla \varphi$$

> Now, what about if I want simplify $(\Delta \varphi)\phi$, would it be something like 
>   $$(\Delta\varphi) \phi=\nabla \cdot(\nabla \phi)\varphi-\nabla \phi \cdot \nabla \varphi \quad ?$$
>   If yes, why?

It might be easy to figure out, but it is not apparent to me.

Comment: isn't multiplication of complex valued functions commutative? Or what am I missing?

Comment: What is $\Delta \varphi $ for a complex function ?

Comment: @Calvin.  I guess so. But the product in the left-handside $\phi\Delta\varphi $ is not in general scalar-valued in $\mathbb{R}^d$, right? Oh! Do you mean since the laplacian is scalar so the product in the left-handside is commutative and the same is extended to the right-handside?

Comment: @idm. $\Delta \varphi$ must be complex-valued too.

Comment: Are $\phi,\varphi$ scalars?

Comment: @idm I presume OP means $\varphi :\mathbb R^d \mapsto \mathbb C$ or maybe even $\mathbb C^n$.

Comment: @idm. I mean $\varphi: \mathbb{R}^d\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ precisely.

Comment: @ Calvin: $\phi$ and $\varphi$ are complex-valued scalar fields just as defined above in the comment.

Comment: OK, in which case yes, $\Delta \varphi$ and $\phi$ are $\mathbb C$-valued, so $ (\Delta \varphi ) \phi = \phi (\Delta \varphi ) $ and now refer to first equation.

Comment: Oh, great. Thanks a lot guys @CalvinKhor and idm.